# Plotting graph to extrapolate a data point which is quite far from the observation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, graphing-functions, interpolation

I am feeding a data set which is of the following form,

```
x = 10^1, y = 5
x = 10^2, y = 7
x = 10^3, y = 14
```

Now, I want to find the y value for x = 10^6. Now, there are different extrapolating methods. But my question is if I consider x = 1, 2 and 3 instead of 10^1, 10^2 and 10^3 and find the value of x = 6 instead of 10^6, does it affect the extrapolation?

N.B. I have actually tried to extrapolate using log(y) values to put both the axis on the same log parameter. But the extrapolation is coming to be unrealistic.

Comment: You can't just randomly extrapolate a graph like that and expect any sensible result. What data is it and what kind of relationship it is expected to follow? If you don't know the answer, you might as well pick any random number.

Comment: @calcstudent, no it is not random. In practical scenario, I am performing an experiment with the parameter of x=10^n and the result is recieved in y=m time. Now, based on that data set I am extrapolating the time required for a higher x. Now, I get it that extrapolation will not give me accurate result as the data points are neither linear, nor quadratic or so. But if that would have known then I could have sharpen the algo of extrapolation.

Comment: but that's precisely the problem. Your experiment probably have random noise in it that can severely skew the result. If you know how the experiment is performed, you might be able to figure out a model that characterize the relationship between the variables, then perform regression. Perhaps the relationship would have log in it, or maybe it doesn't, If you don't know that, what you're doing so far are basically random guesses.

Comment: Three data points is very shaky grounds for anything statistical.